# How do I properly implement git submodules using Gitolite?

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitolite

I would like to create submodules within my hosted repository using Gitolite.  Submodules are easy enough in git outside of Gitolite.  However, Gitolite seems to complicate things.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on why Gitolite is complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

It's no different than having a second repository side by side. Once you create the second repository like you did for the first, add a submodule to the first one using the same url that you have for the second one when you created it.

```
git submodule add <same url as if you were just cloning> <some path>
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Hope this helps.